# Text too close to the edge when aligned to the right for input field

Tags: html, css

Currently wondering how does one give a little space to the right so the text on the input field is not too close to the edge.

```html
<span class="test">
   <input type="text" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputRRPDiscount" style="text-align:right;"> %
</span>
<br>
```

So when typing, the text is aligned to the right, which is fine, however, I feel it is a little too close to the border of the input box and wanted to distance from it a little. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Just add padding to your `<input/>`.

```css
input { padding-right: 5px; }
```

```html
<span class="test"><input type="text" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputRRPDiscount" style="text-align:right;"> %</span>
<br>
```

**Bonus Answer:**

> Just curious is there a way to uniquely use the input
>   type rather then just input. Such as .inputRRPDiscount .input?

You can actually target your selectors many different ways. Such as, targeting it via any [HTML elements with specific attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) or any number of [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). Here are some examples: `input#inputRRPDiscount`, `input[accuracy="2"]`, `input[type="text"][max="100"]`, `span.test > input#inputRRPDiscount[min="0"]`.

Comment: Many thanks. Just curious is there a way to uniquely use the input type rather then just input. Such as .inputRRPDiscount .input?

Comment: @alexjohnson if you've found the answer helpful to you, please mark it as accepted so it can help others.

Answer (score 2):

Add padding-right attribute to style, defining the number of pixels

```
<input type="text" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputRRPDiscount" style="text-align:right;padding-right: 2px;">
```

Anyway, I suggest you to define a css class

```
<input type="text" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputRRPDiscount" class="myInput">
```

In your CSS you'll have:

```
.myInput{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css:

```
input{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a little bit of padding,like this

```css
input{
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="test"><input type="text" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputRRPDiscount" style="text-align:right;"> %</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).

```
style="text-align:right; padding-right: 10px;"
```